# How to change the display of time in datetime column?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this MySQL table:

```
TagName, DateTime, Value
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0013.PV_Top_Temp', '2022-07-05 12:01:40.8440000', '108.1'
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0013.PV_Bot_Temp', '2022-07-05 12:01:40.3440000', '8.6'
```

I would like to change the time from 12:01:40.840000 to 12:01:40 but I do not know how.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Use, for example, DATE_FORMAT(). Or CAST() to DATETIME. *I have this MySQL table* The datetime column is VARCHAR?

Comment: @Akina it is a varchar. Anyway I also tried to separate the time from the datetime with time() = ‘12:01:40’ but it does not retrieve anything and only gives me 0 row. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: If this is VARCHAR value and you need the time part only then you may use even `SUBSTRING(column FROM 12 FOR 8)`. *Do you have any clue why?* You must show your query text.

Comment: @Akina I followed your suggestion and used this: select * from testingintern where substring(DateTime,-1,8) = ‘12:01:40’ but it still gives me 0 row

Comment: What does `-1` as second parameter value should mean? Please study the function description firstly.

Comment: It’s the same as 12 but from the back so it’s -1. Nvm i confused this with another function. But i did change -1 to 12 but it still gives me 0 row

Comment: I don't understand where it was possible to make a mistake - but you did it. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc1a85d176dff879e0c1e6db4d6cc16a